# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy -no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, spring-test

I am getting this exception when I run a test case(Junit) for spring application.

I searched for this problem and I got the information that whenever a lazy initialization occurs and my application tries to get second level data while session is closed(object become detached) then this error occurs, we can't make initialization as EAGER as its performance issue.

My testing class contains  :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass extends AbstractControllerTest {

@Rule
public TestName testMethodName = new TestName();
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
           super.setUp();
        }
       @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        super.tearDown();
         }
 @Test
  public void myTestMethod ()
 {
    assertTrue("Response Validating",validate(baseEntity,perform()));
 }

}
```

Is there a way that can I put  method assertTrue("Response Validating",validate(baseEntity,perform())); in a transaction can bind with current session or with new session so that my detached object become persistent object and then My application can get second level data also. I searched for this problem and I found a solution on link :  http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/hibernate_spring_simulating_an_opensessioninviewfilter
but this link does not fulfil my requirement as it requires target object on which transaction is to be created.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-tx

Comment: If you have a solution please mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 26):

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void myTestMethod ()
{
       assertTrue("Response Validating",validate(baseEntity,perform()));
}
```

Comment: I can't use @Transactional on myTestMethod or on class level because if I use this annotation then after getting response from server Junit become unresponsive(error occurs) because if I use this annotation here it means upper level transaction in which controller class will lie so transaction never closes in that case I have to restart our database. Any further response will be appreciated.

Comment: There are two @Transactional annotation available. javax.transaction.Transactional and org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional. Which one should we use here ?

Comment: I tried with org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional annotation and it worked

Answer (score 9):

Annotate `myTestMethod` with `@Transactional` (assuming you're using annotation-based configuration).

Comment: I can't use @Transactional on myTestMethod or on class level because if I use this annotation then after getting response from server Junit become unresponsive(error occurs) because if I use this annotation here it means upper level transaction in which controller class will lie so transaction never closes in that case I have to restart our database.  Any further response will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand your comment. Are you saying that you have conflicting transaction management running? If something like this can hang your database, you have a serious configuration error on it somewhere and need to speak to a DBA.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this problem. I was implementing OpenSessionInViewFilter in my testing code to overcome this problem but was doing silly mistake.

Please take a look on following code :

```
@Autowired
BeanFactory bf;

    @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception
        {
             sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) bf.getBean("sessionFactory");
            Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true);
            session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.NEVER);
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));
    }

    @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception
        {
            super.tearDown();
            SessionHolder sessionHolder = (SessionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(sessionFactory);
            Session session = sessionHolder.getSession();
            SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(session);

        }
```

Earlier I was not using 
`session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.NEVER)` this was the mistake.

BTW thanks

Answer (score -2):

I also got this error due to using `(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` in the entity.

FetchType.Lazy means the object won’t be loaded to the Session context until it is accessed in code.

This error occurs when we try to fetch a lazy-loaded object from the database using a proxy object.

Then I used `(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`. After that, this issue was solved for me.

Comment: From the question: *"we can't make initialization as EAGER as its performance issue"*.